# Outer measure of a Countable Intersection of Open Sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, outer-measure

Show that if A is a measurable set then there is a Gδ (a countable intersection of open sets) set G with A ⊂ G
and µ
∗
(G − A) = 0.

Where $\mu^{*}$ denotes outer measure.

I understand that since A is countable, its outer measure is 0, but I'm not sure why that would make the outer measure of G-A 0

Comment: What makes you think that any measurable set is countable?

Comment: Please use latex in math formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_N=A \cap [-N,N]$. For each $k$ there is an open set $U_{N,k}$ such that $A_N \subset U_{N,k}$ and $m(U_{N,k}\setminus A_N) <\frac 1 {2^{N}k}$. Now $m(\bigcup_N U_{N,k}\setminus A) \leq \sum_N \frac 1 {2^{N}k}= \frac 1  k$. Let $U_k=\bigcup_N U_{N,k}$ The $U$ is open, $A \subset U$ and $m(U_k \setminus A) \leq \frac 1 k$. Finally, $G=\bigcap_k U_k$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set containing $A$ such that $m(G\setminus A)=0$.

Comment: Since $A_N$ is bounded, for each $N$, the sets $E_N$ can be bounded also, in which case your $E$ will be bounded and fail to include $A$.  Maybe you meant $\bigcup$ instead of $\bigcap$ in the definition of $E$, but then it's not clear that $E$ is a $G_\delta$ set.   I think that, in the infinite measure case, you'll need to build sets analogous to your $G_n$'s by taking unions, and then build the desired $E$ as an intersection of those.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you for your comment. I have edited may answer.